# Diagonalizable binary matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, finite-rings

I'm trying to figure out the following question:

Are symmetric, binary $n\times n$ matrices with zeros on the diagonal, are diagonalizable over $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

I know that it isn't true that $\textit{any}$ binary matrix is invertible over $\mathbb{Z}_2$, but I'm not sure about what happens in $\mathbb{Z}_4$, in particular in the case where the diagonal is all-zero.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, notice that if $R$ is an invertible matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ then $\det(R)$ is an invertible element of $\mathbb{Z}_4$. So $\det(R)=1$  or $\det(R)=3$.

If $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \lambda  & 0\\ 0 & \mu \end{pmatrix}$ then  $\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ \lambda a & \mu b\end{pmatrix}$

Hence,  $\det\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}=ad-bc=(\mu -\lambda)ab$.

Next, notice that
$$-1.(ad-bc)=\det\left(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\right)=\det\left(\begin{pmatrix} \lambda a & \mu b\\ \lambda c & \mu d\end{pmatrix}\right)=\lambda\mu (ad-bc).$$

If $ad-bc=1$ or $3$ the $\lambda\mu=-1$. Thus, $\mu-\lambda= 2$.

Therefore, $\det\begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}=2ab$.

This contradicts the assumption that $ad-bc=1$ or $3$.

So the matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ can not be written as  $RDR^{-1}$, where $R$ is an invertible matrix with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 0):

[This paper](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272332/1-s2.0-S0021869312X00255/1-s2.0-S0021869312005601/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEEIaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCIHKB5y6GrgEVVNxYQiE9W5zog7%2FjNUGkBQ8DTHaaQAp5AiBQp5sMwkooOhnTWdH1LdZWyWhFrTqwj9RJSz%2B78CZ1Oyq0Awh7EAMaDDA1OTAwMzU0Njg2NSIM5YShAf%2Fp0i1AkBYWKpEDtRgmhb482bAqItxUu8hOgTduW%2Fn6ig7RF5CM2qeSZ3FvJYRyv3GcyZJLEtCr%2BXrhrewtZAAErGEGpQ38zLaAEkqDbhyKgljELWIIEGepTOGguBq6rQiqHcBDZfXTCsp3oFau2v8hBndUpp%2BrLiiJYdfvRgX%2FB3glLw383mG7kOeuet2BgZIcKAE5v9DSoDjAMzpX%2B%2F5SsVG2CRDMALTFbltSPG6p29z1G9r2uEGyWA%2Buy1MIAWuLis5a9aeTltmi4rCxfckZbJ9PnG22t9KvteFABPza2m8QC8rsaXf0wmqw3dz0RtSoUzZ%2FGcwXo68ESsECYMUQewaxV6XtboyOtObYkKvi5ucnDwfLNbp7K1hpUb%2FvH5HBNt04fnbF4hzElMtIFr8rwaoIAgLubCAr8GakvC1N4sL2hUMCoA%2BifYbCuVX5aeBtjuLCa2Uew6kLfBykkUBd9TCqf0YvMGFqCI%2BnBeqIkrrUD2sUQLZt%2B0TVtQLHv8Ee%2FGG4fLR9mvemFHuILGhqgkwvd2MQ%2BYpBqQcw6eHYggY67AE79rblcK6msy46gOMnhWfHt34eQ%2Fa0hlAAt2e0Yo2pnFDW3WOROvQqyEDldNBUZE1JaEgorvsAFCS4KOaeQwaAom0iH%2FKa8JXdrGisQ8abpew7%2BGnLtkD3WWfWOOK3CJHrYsP%2B4q41P%2BIntvXaMmWT9Lk4nQIg4G8JqTLFcwxnhKk%2FSqvIx30ZBm%2FVMuY17d1c4xPljw9qL0iIoVe6ZXNxw9ACyJdvrEOUFb2MmUBQQerFiXdYUTnxr8c3AXuUMnpBNFKoZr4eRFHspzQ7XflTCkIZVHtXlsEHbz7j%2BsaO3SIiCCxwNcfCpeBe5Q%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20210320T181337Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTY4ZHJBYH3%2F20210320%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=6f11872c8b5d12591c67b208c95246ab705a0215febf8dea143889a2fc45e00e&hash=a81bcc269e1ce9da78f5e16d78d0624b46b2b9926bb4825b915f49ab85d8d7c6&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0021869312005601&tid=spdf-34d222f9-3571-48f1-8971-4efb43917f75&sid=883da4c35a07c54cd7290065b0826d4ff0f3gxrqa&type=client) sounds relevant, but I don't know anything about matrices over commutative rings.  I don't understand the second sentence of the abstract!

I tried to post this has a comment, but the link to the paper wouldn't fit.

Comment: Why are there only 64 possibilities? I'm asking about $n\times n$ matrices (changed the question to state that specifically).

Comment: @GuyWberg Whoops, for some reason, I thought you were asking about $4\times4$ matrices.  Sorry.